# date is added in background while adding time in datastore GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

3.Why does "jan 1st 1970" gets added in the startime field in datastore when I am doing the below statements?

```
    (hour,min) = self.request.get('starttime').split(":")
    #if either of them is null or empty string then int will throw exception
    if hour and min :
        datastoremodel.starttime = datetime.time(int(hour), int(min))
```

Although when I retrieve it only time comes through? I wonder what date is doing in datastore? Any clues?

Comment: what is the type of datastoremodel.starttime

Answer (score 2):

google app engine [doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#TimeProperty) says

```
class TimeProperty(verbose_name=None, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, ...)
A time property, without a date. Takes a Python standard library datetime.time value. See DateTimeProperty for more information.
Value type: datetime.time. This is converted to a datetime.datetime internally.
```

so to convert time to a date , start of [epoch time "jan 1st 1970"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is added

Comment: anyway what's your worry abt how google saves it internally as far as you get correct time back?